# Div está herdando altura do css até certo ponto, depois desconfigura! Como corrigir?

Tags: php, html, css

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até no ponto da seta azul estão alinhadas, depois quando o texto é maior no lado esquerdo, o lado direito não segue a altura. como corrgir?

css:

```
.content-goal {
  padding: 4px;
}
```

Código resumido:

Lado esquerdo,

```
<div class="col-xs-12 content-goal text-left border-right border-left border-bottom"><?= $conceitos[$i]['sys_id'] ?>. <?= $conceitos[$i]['description'] ?></div>
```

lado direito,

```
<div class="col-xs-3 content-goal text-center border-bottom border-right"><?= $status ?></div>
```

Código completo da tabela:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 header-goal border-top border-left border-right">OBJETIVOS DE APRENDIZAGEM E DESENVOLVIMENTO</div>

    <?php
      // Cria array de conceitos de acordo com o Type (Pré-escola - maternal)
      $conceitos = $this->db->get_where('learning_goals', array(
        'class_id' => $class_id,
        'section_id' => $section_id,
        'type' => $curType,
      ))->result_array();

      $eixos = [];
      $_subjects = [];

      foreach($conceitos as $conceito) {
        if(in_array($conceito['subject_id'], $_subjects))
          continue;

        array_push($_subjects, $conceito['subject_id']);

        $subject = $this->db->get_where('subject', array(
          'subject_id' => $conceito['subject_id'],
        ))->row();
    ?>

        <div class="col-xs-12" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">
          <div class="col-xs-12 header-goal border-left border-right border-bottom border-top"><?php echo $subject->name; ?></div>
          <?php

            for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($conceitos); $i++) {
              if(strcmp($conceito['subject_id'], $conceitos[$i]['subject_id']) != 0)
                continue;
          ?>
          <div class="col-xs-12 content-goal text-left border-right border-left border-bottom"><?= $conceitos[$i]['sys_id'] ?>. <?= $conceitos[$i]['description'] ?></div>
          <?php
            }
          ?>
        </div>

    <?php
      }
    ?>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">
    <div class="col-xs-12 header-goal text-center border-top border-right">BIMESTRE</div>
    <?php
      $lastSubject = '';

      for($j = 0; $j < sizeof($conceitos); $j++) {
        if(strcmp($lastSubject, $conceitos[$j]['subject_id']) != 0) {

        ?>
          <div style="margin-left: -1px" class="col-xs-3 header-goal text-center border-bottom border-top">1º</div>
          <div style="margin-left: 0px" class="col-xs-3 header-goal text-center border-bottom border-top border-left">2º</div>
          <div style="margin-left: 0px" class="col-xs-3 header-goal text-center border-bottom border-top border-left">3º</div>
          <div style="margin-right: 0px" class="col-xs-3 header-goal border-left text-center border-bottom border-top border-right">4º</div>
        <?php
        }

        $lastSubject = $conceitos[$j]['subject_id'];

        for($k = 1; $k <= 4; $k++) {
          $status = $this->db->get_where('learning_goals_status', array(
            'student_id' => $stu->student_id,
            'conceito_id' => $conceitos[$j]['id'],
            'exam_id' => $k,
          ))->row();

          if(!$status)
            $status = '-';
          else
            $status = $status->status;
            ?>
          <div class="col-xs-3 content-goal text-center border-bottom border-right"><?= $status ?></div>
          <?php
        }
      }
    ?>
  </div>
```

Uma solução que me foi útil foi definir no css o tamanho do height com !important:

```
.content-goal {
  padding: 4px;
  height: 40px !important;
}
```

Comment: Seu problema é com css e html. Coloque o código da tabela. Apenas com esses dois códigos não é possível (ao meu ver) criar uma solução

Comment: Coloquei o código da tabela.

Comment: Acho que deveria usar `table` para criar tabelas, e não divs.

Comment: Nesse caso em especial, precisei usar as divs. Mas encontrei a solução. Vou colocá-la na pergunta!

Comment: Use tabelas e não divs